# getting primary outlook account win32 python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I iterate through all the active outlook accounts to find a specifically defined sender account.
Later I want to BCC the primary account of the same outlook profile. how can I do that?

```
#find sender account. If account not active, will send from primary active
sender = None
for oacc in outlook.Session.Accounts:
    if oacc.SmtpAddress == sendFrom:
        sender = oacc
        break
mail._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, sender))
```

above finds the designated sender account (sendFrom).

Later in the code I try to BCC the primary account. But im not sure how to do that. I assume outlook.Session.Accounts, which can be iterated through, would store the primary account in index 0. is that correct?

```
if BCC==True:
    mail.BCC = primary_account
```

Comment: so i got this working. But now all of a sudden it throwing a typeerror for the sender part of this. Saying Accounts object is not iterable. It was literally working less than an hour ago.